# Add/Update from Offline DBs to Central DB - Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, merge

I've got a somewhat unique problem due to our infrastructure. I have two **offline** tablet's which are performing a survey and entering the information in an Access database. These tablets have their own copy of the database front end AND back end.

I need to, at the end of every day, update the master copy of the back-end (on an office computer) with the values in each of the two tablet databases. This master DB is then uploaded to each of the tablets, replacing their incomplete versions, and off they go the next day.

I've never done this sort of merging before and don't really know where to start. Basically, I need a query which will:

- Delete the current values in the master DB
- Add the values from tablet1, merged with the values of tablet2 into the master DB

I can delete the current values in the master DB because the tablets will contain the values from the days before as well (as they are sometimes needed for reference etc). Basically, the tablets will always contain the `entire database + today's survey`. It's just that `+ today's survey` is different for each tablet.

Is it possible to do? How can I keep the ID fields, as there are relationships in place using KeyIDs?

I need `MERGE`, but havn't found any documentation on if it works in MS Access... MS seems to play with the standards however they please. Or maybe MSA2010 just hasn't updated to support Merge?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed MSSQL was the syntax for Jet. I could be mistaken. It is for a standard Access Jet database, using the VBA/SQL syntax in Access. I will edit my question to dissolve the ambiguity.

Comment: I've read that Access 2010 supports an off-line capability with SharePoint as a data source.  If you can substitute SharePoint for "master DB", perhaps the built-in off-line/on-line & synchronize features would simplify this situation.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/synchronize-a-sharepoint-2010-list-with-access-2010-HA101854203.aspx

Comment: I wish I had known about that sooner. It would have been the best way to go by the looks of it. I have found a work-around for now though.. so I think (since it's a sort of temporary database, used by 2 people for about 8 months) I'll save myself the hassle of transferring everything to SharePoint. Definitely a good idea though.

Comment: I'll post my workaround. Though I think for future users, you should share your SharePoint idea as an answer. It does solve the problem, and in a much more elegant and 'proper' way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that works for me as a bandaid solution. I empty the existing Master table first. I then use:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable IN "LocationToTablet1/backend_tablet1.mdb"
UNION
SELECT * FROM myTable IN "LocationToTablet2/backend_tablet2.mdb"
```

and name that query "myQuery". Then

```
INSERT INTO myTable IN "LocationToOffice/master_backend.mdb"
SELECT * FROM [myQuery]
```

However for anyone having the same question, HansUp's solution of integrating with SharePoint seems like a good idea (see question's comments). It does not require end-user intervention, whereas I need to manually call these queries when the tablets return to the office.

Comment: It works like this: let's say on day five, there's 100 rows of data. On day six, tablet1 adds another 4 rows and tablet 2 adds another 7 rows. At the end of day six, there is then a total of 100+4+7 rows. The above deletes 100 rows from the master DB, then would add the 100+4 from the first tablet UNION (not UNION ALL) 100+7 from the second tablet to make 111 rows in the master DB. I then delete the DB on both tablets and re-upload the whole thing. It ensures tablet1 can't do something tablet2 has already done (proper keys/relationships restrict doing the same thing twice)